# ruby depends on... old gem version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I work at `spree` app(`v. 0.70.5`), but I need to install some gem which depends on `spree v. 0.70.0`. This app already work at production and I don't know can I rollback spree version (to `0.70.0`) or not.

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the change log between the versions, if nothing jumps at you, try using 0.70.0

```
gem "spree", "0.70.0"
```

and test your app

Alternatively you can fork the gem that has dependency on the older version of spree and try to upgrade it

Comment: Thanks! But I find compatible gem branch with me spree version.